# How to set dynamically created tablelayout cell height & width fixed

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am beginner in android. How to set dynamically created table layout cell height & width fixed.

Click [here](http://i1371.photobucket.com/albums/ag293/shanalalkasim/AndroidError_zpsaf4bef98.png) for screenshot

[image]

The cell height & width was changing based on text size. i need all cell size as fixed.

XML code is

```
    <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/main"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"                                 
            android:orientation="vertical"  
            android:weightSum="100"  >
 </LinearLayout>
```

My code is

```
Main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);

    Main_1 = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams sudoku_1_lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    Main_1.setLayoutParams(sudoku_1_lp);
    Main_1.setWeightSum(100);
    Main_1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    Main_1.setId(100);

    //Layout for sudoku_board 
    sudokuboard = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams sudokuboard_lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,0,80.0f);
    sudokuboard_lp.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
    sudokuboard.setLayoutParams(sudokuboard_lp);
    sudokuboard.setWeightSum(80);
    sudokuboard.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sudokuboard.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
    sudokuboard.setId(102);

    tblsudoku = new TableLayout(this);
    TableLayout.LayoutParams sudoku_tbl_lp = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,80.0f);
    sudoku_tbl_lp.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);
    tblsudoku.setLayoutParams(sudoku_tbl_lp);
    tblsudoku.setId(103);

    for(int i=0; i < 9; i++)
    {
            TableRow NewRow1 =new TableRow(this);

            TableLayout.LayoutParams n1 = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,0,10.0f);
            if(i==3 || i==6  )
            {
                n1.setMargins(0,2, 0, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                n1.setMargins(0,1, 0, 0);
            }

            NewRow1.setLayoutParams(n1);

            for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
            {
                TextView tv_00 = new TextView(this);
                int id=10*i;
                id=id+j;
                id=id*id*id;
                String strText=""+id;

                tv_00.setText(strText);
                TableRow.LayoutParams r1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 10.0f);
                if(j==2 || j==5  )
                {
                    r1.setMargins(0, 0, 2, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                    r1.setMargins(0, 0, 1, 0);
                }

                tv_00.setLayoutParams(r1);
                tv_00.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);                   
                tv_00.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                tv_00.setId(id);
                tv_00.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

                NewRow1.addView(tv_00);
            }
            tblsudoku.addView(NewRow1);
    }
    sudokuboard.addView(tblsudoku); 
    Main_1.addView(sudokuboard);
    Main.addView(Main_1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the **maximum** possible number in ur layout by using any algo.
Then decide layout params accordingly and set it to textview .

```
int anywidth = 0; //Decide according to possible max text length 
int anyheight = 0; //Decide according to passible max text length
TableRow.LayoutParams r1 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(anywidth, anyheight, 10.0f);
```